# Use DataFrame column as index and append duplicates as new columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that contains a column with dates which I'd like to use as my DataFrame's index. The dates in that column are not necessarily unique - sometimes there might be duplicates. **I wish to append duplicates as new columns**. Dates that are unique can just contain NaN (or whatever) for the newly appended columns.

To clarify I'll provide an example:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [
        {'Date':'01-01-2020','A':0,'B':1},
        {'Date':'01-01-2020','A':2,'B':3},
        {'Date':'02-01-2020','A':4,'B':5},
        {'Date':'02-01-2020','A':6,'B':7},
        {'Date':'03-01-2020','A':8,'B':9},
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

This will yield:

```py
    Date        A   B
0   01-01-2020  0   1
1   01-01-2020  2   3
2   02-01-2020  4   5
3   02-01-2020  6   7
4   03-01-2020  8   9
```

What I want:

```py
            A   B   C   D
Date        
01-01-2020  0   1   2   3
02-01-2020  4   5   6   7
03-01-2020  8   9   NaN NaN
```

The naming of the newly appended columns can be arbitrary. I don't even know whether appending would be the right way to go about it. Maybe it's easier to create a new DataFrame from scratch.

Comment: What if a row is repeated more  than twice?  will there be AB CD and EF??

Comment: Yes, more than twice should result in even more appended columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for unpivot data and then pivoting by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index('Date').stack().reset_index(name='val')

df = df1.set_index(['Date', df1.groupby('Date').cumcount()])['val'].unstack()
print (df)
              0    1    2    3
Date                          
01-01-2020  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0
02-01-2020  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0
03-01-2020  8.0  9.0  NaN  NaN
```

If order of output values is not important:

```
df1 = df.melt('Date')

df = df1.set_index(['Date', df1.groupby('Date').cumcount()])['value'].unstack()
print (df)
              0    1    2    3
Date                          
01-01-2020  0.0  2.0  1.0  3.0
02-01-2020  4.0  6.0  5.0  7.0
03-01-2020  8.0  9.0  NaN  NaN
```

Another idea is use lambda function for reshape:

```
df = (df.set_index('Date')
       .groupby(level=0)
       .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.to_numpy().ravel()))
       .unstack())

print (df)
              0    1    2    3
Date                          
01-01-2020  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0
02-01-2020  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0
03-01-2020  8.0  9.0  NaN  NaN
```